# Mixpanel.track from the controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixpanel, analytical

I have an application that has a simple form submission (an email). I have MixPanel's tracking analytics integrated into the app, and want to track every time an interaction with this form happens--specifically, when a user successfully/unsuccessfully submits the form, and what their email is.

After doing some research, it seems simplest method is to track at the controller level (where I am running validations, and making the overall decision whether or not the submission is legitimate). This would require running a JS function from the controller. Is this possible? Is there a better method of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Let integrate this gem [analytical](https://github.com/jkrall/analytical).

Then just follow the instruction in above link, but here is the summary:

1. Add `analytical` to your controller
2. Setup mixpanel token in `config/analytical.yml`

   ```
   production:
     mixpanel:
       key: your_mixpanel_project_token
   development:
     # Also define here if you want to test in development
   test:
   ```
3. Track your event in controller:

   ```
   # data_key_1, data_value_1, data_key_2 and data_value_2 are the data
   #  which were attached to mixpanel event, they are example, specify yours
   analytical.event 'Your event', data_key_1: data_value_1, data_key_2: data_value_2
   ```

You may integrate more with GA, KISSMetrics, or whatever you want, the tracking code works in generic, this also works with javascript code, for more detail, please refer its [documentation](https://github.com/jkrall/analytical).

Comment: Trying to test this. I added analytical to my gemfile & bundle installed, created the config yaml file, and added the call in my controller, however my controller is not recognizing the 'analytical' variable. Did I miss something?